# Is it possible to navigate to symbol in class in Rider/Resharper?

Tags: resharper, rider

There is an option to navigate to symbol in file, but if a file contains many classes it is not very helpful.

Is there an option to navigate within the current class?

In VS we have combo boxes at the top of the file that let us choose the class and the symbol within the class.
In Rider it is possible to open the file structure and look for the symbol there, but it is less convenient.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the file-specific [Go to File Member](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_File_Member.html) that you mentioned, try using the more generic [Search Everywhere](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Searching_Everywhere.html) that looks for symbols globally. From there, you can filter to only include members in a certain class: for example, if you're looking for `myMember` in `ClassFoo`, enter something like `cf mm` (or the full `ClassFoo myMember` if you're not a fan of lowerCamelHumps).

I would expect *Go to File Member* to also support this kind of filters but it looks like it doesn't.